# Remove consecutive vertical bar in JS string

Tags: javascript, regex

is there a good RegExp for replacing 2 or more vertical bar characters ( "||" ) from a string into one vertical bar ("|") ? I am using AngularJS 1.5.7. $scope.outputValue is an array which I am converting to string, and implementing 2 different RegExps afterwards:

```
$scope.outputValue   =     $scope.outputValue.toString();
$scope.outputValue   =     $scope.outputValue.replace(/,/g, "|");
$scope.outputValue   =     $scope.outputValue.replace(/[\s,]+/g, ' ');
```

Problem is that, depending on the users input inside a textarea, my array gives similar results such as these (duplicating the vertical pipebar separator):

```
$scope.outputValue = ["one" | "two" | "three" ||| "four" || "five" ];
```

and it should go like this:

```
$scope.outputValue = ["one" | "two" | "three" | "four" | "five" ];
```

Thanks, Nenad

Comment: `.replace(/\|\|/g, '|')`

Comment: BTW.  `["one" | "two" | "three" ||| "four" || "five" ]` is not valid JavaScript

Comment: @Tibrogargan I don't think that will do what's desired; it'll leave extra `|` when there's more than two pipes.

Comment: @DaveNewton good catch.  Failed to read the question properly.  `.replace(/\|\|+/g, '|')`

Comment: @Tibrogargan I don't think specifying two pipes is required here, though; just replace one or more with one, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton it's a comment, not an answer.  And frankly, replacing "|" with "|" seems like a bunch of unnecessary work.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I figure comments might as well be correct, but that's just me.

Comment: @DaveNewton If we're being really nit picky, `\|{2,}` is even better than `\|+`

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yup, or \|\|+, but we digress :)

Comment: @Tibrogargan thanks mate, I would like to try something else as well. Is there a way to modify this RegExp to something that would replace "| | | | |" with "|"? Meaning, I'll need to count whitespaces as well. Thank you!

Comment: @kneles90 this would work `\|(\s*\|)+`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `+` quantifier. Read it as "one or more". It's great for matching and reducing sequences, like squashing multiple spaces, where you'll often see something like this:

```js
console.log('foo|bar||baz|||quux||||norf|||||'.replace(/\|+/g, '|'))
```

Comment: I believe the proper metasyntactic variables would be plugh, then xyzzy :D (Hmm, although https://gist.github.com/hail2u/6561431 disagrees with me :(

Comment: @DaveNewton whoa, that's great, I haven't seen most of these used before. I've been collecting them passively because they're very useful, but I wasn't really aware of just how special and dear they are to me. I declare "asdf" to be a very large member of the set. <3 asdf |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Comment: As i am not going to open a question for that, can you guys briefly tell me why are metasyntactic variables so important to you? :p I never use it I don't get the purpose even though I read wikipedia article about it. it is just placeholder right? you better use real variable names lol!

Comment: @antoni A lot of it is for hysterical raisins (also something worth looking up)-they're part of computing history :) Obvious placeholders have a legitimate use, though; they're unambiguous reminders that the specifics of what's being discussed don't rely on domain or business knowledge-clearly generic references.

Comment: @FilipDupanović Yep, they're interesting and fun!

Comment: Thanks @FilipDupanović that did work, however I would like to try something else as well. Is there a way to improve this RegExp that you wrote to something that would replace "| | | | |" with "|"? Meaning, I'll need to count whitespaces as well. Many thanks!